# Button text is greyed out in android google map

Tags: android, android-xml, android-maps-v2

I have a button I placed ontop of my google map, but the text is all grayed out like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to make the text not grayed out so it will be easier to read?

My xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate to Brewery"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="getMap"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That seems to be orange to me. Darker orange than the background, but orange. #D38100 is definitely not gray

Answer (score 0):

android:textColor="@color/orange"

Try using white instead